# Why does Backbone.js create a new element for a view?

Tags: backbone.js, template-engine

When working with views in Backbone.js, I usually have the following parts:

- A target element where the view shall be attached to, e.g. a `ul` element.
- A template that represents a list item.
- An `el` element on the view, in this case an `li` element.

If I render the view Backbone.js creates the `li` element and then I usually attach this rendered thing to the target element, e.g. using jQuery.

So far, so good.

What I don't get is why Backbone.js creates the `li` programmatically. Why does it not just take the template's content and use that for rendering?

To me, this seems confusing, because:

- In the surrounding HTML page, I have a `ul` tag.
- In the template *which shall represent a list item* I do **NOT** have an `li` tag.

Insted the `li` is created programmatically by Backbone.js and filled with the template.

Why is this?

IMHO it would be more straight-forward if the template already contained the `li`. What am I missing?

Comment: I thought it was odd at first too, until I realized that always having an anchor element, especially when dealing with no templates (programmatically generated) and dynamically downloaded templates made my backbonejs life far more consistent.

Comment: I think backbone attaches all events you define in view to parent element and then delegates its to respective elements.So it needs to know the parent elements in your case 'li' to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is Backbone needs an element to attach the template to and manipulate.  If Backbone were to attach to a DOM element that was on the page right away, each time the element was updated (items added) the process would be much slower. There are many tutorials online explaining how it is better to first generate your output prior to appending it to the DOM.  For instance, if I had a <ul> tag and I wanted to append 200 <li> elements, you would notice a significant delay if I just appended each <li> versus building the html in memory and appending it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I don't know whether this is *THE* reason, but this one perfectly makes sense. Thanks :-)!